# Any shown/hidden events for JavaFX node?

Tags: java, javafx

Can I determine a moment, when a node was actually shown/hidden in JavaFX?

But "shown" I mean any part of node graphics is shown, by "hidden" I mean entire node is somehow hidden, including overlapping by other nodes and/or setting visible to false.

Also ok for some descendants of [`Node`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/Node.html).

Comment: Are you talking about isVisible() ?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#isVisible--

Comment: No. When `visible` is set to `true`, then node can still be invisible, if it is overlapped by other node or not connected to the graph.

Comment: Yea I assumed you probably wanted more use. I don't know of any method that will do behavior  you want unfortunately although would be useful. Seems like you might have to create your own that traverses through the set of nodes and checks if any overlapping nodes obscure your node or if your node is outside the bound of the screen :\

Comment: I can't traverse all graph 50 times per second, I need a reasonable trigger for this. This could be `onShown` or `onHidden` events, but I don't see ones.

Comment: Typically it shouldn't be necessary to interact with nodes at this low a level in JavaFX. The way JavaFX works is that the state of nodes is represented by observable properties. If a property changes, the relevant portion of the scene is repainted on the next layout pass (next rendering frame), so all you have to do is change the state of a node and it will automatically be repainted, if it is visible (in your sense). There are a couple of hooks into the lower-level workings: you can override `Parent.layoutChildren()` and force layout with `requestLayout()`, for example.